# How to use $LSB_JOBINDEX to call different scripts?

Tags: jobs, lsf

I know I can pass `$LSB_JOBINDEX` to a script and then execute the script I actually want based on the index but I would rather do everything in one command.

My scripts are located in a directory like:

Script1

Script2

.

.

.

Script10

I would like to run:

`bsub - J myArray[1-10] Script\$LSB_JOBINDEX`

Does anyone know if there is a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way without getting into a mess with escaping and quoting is just to execute everything from a single script that dispatches to the other ones:

```
bsub -J myArray[1-10] dispatcher.sh
```

where `dispatcher.sh` looks something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
realscript="Script${LSB_JOBINDEX}"
eval realscript
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these worked for me.

```
bsub -J[1-10] './Script${LSB_JOBINDEX}'
bsub -J[1-10] '/bin/sh Script${LSB_JOBINDEX}'
```

good luck!